# Do I need statistical test with nested-cv?

Tags: cross-validation, validation, unbiased-estimator

I'm working with a small data set and with 4 algorithms. The optimization process showed to be Very important as long as it improves a lot their performances. So, I'm using 10x5 nested-cv to estimate my algorithms performance, in this case errors since I'm using regressors.

My doubt is, in order to see if some algorithm or some feature combination outperform others, should I do some statistical test in my 10x5 nested-cv? How should I do this?

An detail is: besides my dataset is small, it's start to get real expensive to run these CV. So that's why I'm using 10x5...